# Tree,Nodes,Type of Trees

Tags: java, binary-tree

I want to create a tree that detect if the insert is a Object of type Characters it will compare each one and decide where to insert [ right or left ],( i know it can detect by position in ascii table) ,and if the insert is an object of int it will do the same operation.
My Questions:

1. I need to create the tree and on the same time to set a compartor ( for example if its a tree of Chars it will be a Chars_comperator that checks Chars and he implements Comparator ( of java ).?
2. My code now is good for int only. becuase i take the object convert to string and then to int and after all this i compare and decide where to insert, this is how i need to do it? or there is another way to do it that can take care all of kinds of Objects?
Here is my code and how i create the tree,

**Tree class**

```
public class tree {

bNode root;
public tree() {
    this.root = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return root==null;
}
public void insert(Object data)
{
    if(isEmpty())
        this.root = new bNode(data);
    else
        this.root.insert(data);

   }
 }
```

**bNode Class**

```
public class bNode {
 protected Object data;
 protected bNode left;
 protected bNode right;


public bNode(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

public void insert(Object data){

    if(Integer.parseInt(data.toString())<Integer.parseInt(this.data.toString())){
        if(this.left==null)
             this.left = new bNode(data);
        else 
            this.left.insert(data);

    }
    else{
        if(this.right==null)
             this.right = new bNode(data);
        else 
            this.right.insert(data);



    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    tree x = new tree();
    char a = 'G';
    x.insert(a);
    x.insert(60);
    x.insert(40);
    x.insert(30);
    x.insert(59);
    x.insert(61);
    x.root.printTree(x.root);


}
```

}
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of passing an Object, you could pass a `Comparable` in `insert()`.
Standard type like Integer, String, etc. already implement the Conparable interface.

instead of using `if (a <b`) you call

```
compareTo(a,b);
```

See java doc of Comparable.

If, for any reason, you want to stay with Passing an `Object` to `insert()`, you also can solve that by not using toString, but by checking the class of object, and then casting:

```
if (object instanceof Integer) {
    int val = ((Integer) object).intValue();
    // now compare 
} else if (object instance of String) {
     String val .....
    // use val.compareTo()
}
```

Comment: If i create the tree for example BinaryTree x = new BinaryTree(comp) and comp is Comparator comp = new IntegerComparator, so now i know for sure that the tree will be an int tree, so all the checks will be on int then i dont need to ask all the question, ( instanceof..), i mean what i`m really want is to create a functions that implements comparator, each function check another thing, its like the instanceof, for example if i created a IntegerComparator i know that every object will pass the compareTo of integercomparator. i think its more efficient way to do that. isnt it?

Comment: no, just new BinaryTree(); Otherwise you must read more about generics. But the insert(Comparable comp); uses the comparable

Comment: if i want to store the objects as chars i insert it as is?

Comment: Character is the java Object representation for char